# su in Debian chroot gives critical error (embedded system)

Tags: linux, debian, chroot, su, pam

I'm trying to install Debian jessie inside a chroot on a embedded system (QNAP NAS with kernel 2.6.33.2). I successfully run `debootstrap` to install the base system and the chroot works correctly because I'm able to update the packages using `apt-get`.

The problem occurs when adding a new user: `su` always prints **su: Critical error - immediate abort**. Here's a printout:

```
CHROOT:/# whoami
root
CHROOT:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),100(users)
CHROOT:/# su root
su: Critical error - immediate abort
CHROOT:/# adduser newuser
Adding user `newuser' ...
Adding new group `newuser' (1000) ...
Adding new user `newuser' (1000) with group `newuser' ...
Creating home directory `/home/newuser' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:

Retype new UNIX password:

passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for newuser
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Full Name []:
        Room Number []:
        Work Phone []:
        Home Phone []:
        Other []:
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
CHROOT:/# su newuser
su: Critical error - immediate abort
```

and every time I try `su` this error appears on `dmesg`:

```
CHROOT:/# dmesg
CHROOT:/# su root
su: Critical error - immediate abort
CHROOT:/# dmesg
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
[    0.000000] sys_set_ipsec_rules: copy_from_user failed!
```

Is it something related to the old kernel version? Can I do anything to circumvent this issue, as I cannot obviously upgrade the kernel?

By the way, I have a VERY old lenny chroot that was created in this way and in the same system it works correctly.

`strace su root` gives:

```
### CUT ###
read(3, "#\n# /etc/login.defs - Configurat"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, " issuing \n# the \"mesg y\" command"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "It supports passwords of unlimit"..., 4096) = 2286
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb76e7000, 4096)                = 0
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
_llseek(3, 0, [0], SEEK_SET)            = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0xb7666680, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
alarm(10)                               = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
read(3, "", 384)                        = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 10
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1491675822
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_AUDIT) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
sendto(3, "p\0\0\0Q\4\5\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0op=PAM:session_o"..., 112, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 112
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 500)   = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\2477\0\0\0\0\0\0p\0\0\0Q\4\5\0\4\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_PEEK|MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\2477\0\0\0\0\0\0p\0\0\0Q\4\5\0\4\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
close(3)                                = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1491675822
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2492, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76e7000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2492
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb76e7000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "su: Critical error - immediate a"..., 37su: Critical error - immediate abort
) = 37
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_AUDIT) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
sendto(3, "l\0\0\0P\4\5\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0op=PAM:setcred a"..., 108, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 108
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 500)   = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\5\0\0\0004<\0\0\0\0\0\0l\0\0\0P\4\5\0\5\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_PEEK|MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\5\0\0\0004<\0\0\0\0\0\0l\0\0\0P\4\5\0\5\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb73e2000, 8284)                = 0
munmap(0xb7324000, 16500)               = 0
munmap(0xb7320000, 12384)               = 0
munmap(0xb7319000, 24776)               = 0
munmap(0xb72fb000, 119488)              = 0
munmap(0xb73b7000, 163088)              = 0
munmap(0xb7344000, 467256)              = 0
munmap(0xb72ca000, 196956)              = 0
munmap(0xb73df000, 8220)                = 0
munmap(0xb72c7000, 8232)                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the same Debian jessie in another NAS with a **newer kernel** and seeing it **worked**, I managed to identify the culprit by comparing the files in `/etc/pam.d/`: it's **pam_limits.so** (inside the Debian chroot) which I think is not compatible with the outer older kernel.

So, if I inspect the problematic chroot, I can see which services use **pam_limits.so** with:

```bsh
CHROOT:/# grep -l "^session.*pam_limits.so" $(find /etc/pam.d -type f)
/etc/pam.d/runuser
/etc/pam.d/login
/etc/pam.d/su
/etc/pam.d/cron
```

This command searches all the services which by default are enabling **pam_limits.so** to run and you see that `su` is there (that's the reason why it fails). So I can comment out all these by prepending a `#` with `sed` in this way:

```bsh
CHROOT:/# sed -i "/^session.*pam_limits.so/s/^/#/" $(find /etc/pam.d -type f)
CHROOT:/# grep -l "^session.*pam_limits.so" $(find /etc/pam.d -type f)
```

After issuing `sed`, there are no more pam_limits enabled (as `grep` now prints nothing) and in fact the `su` is working without any `dmesg` output:

```bsh
CHROOT:/# whoami
root
CHROOT:/# dmesg
CHROOT:/# su root
CHROOT:/# dmesg
CHROOT:/# exit
exit
CHROOT:/# whoami
root
```